# How to use variable parameters for rotation of a picture

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, rotation, transform

What is wrong with my approach?

I would like to allow a user to enter a value of 0 to 180 degree to rotate a picture by this value.

If I use the code below it works perfect.

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').setAttribute("style", "position:relative;height:1024px;width:100%; transform: rotate(45deg)" );
```

But, if I use variables like in the following code, no rotation is performed.

```
var deg = 45;
var rotation = "transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
document.getElementById('myCanvas').setAttribute("style", "position:relative;height:1024px;width:100%; rotation" );
```

How can I manage my requirement?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Improved formatting & readability. Added relevant tags.

Comment: Hi Gennadii,thanks for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think your problem is because you have missed some concatenation. Try this:

```
var deg = 45;
var rotation = "transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);"; // Note: Extra semicolon in string
var element = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
element.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;height:1024px;width:100%;" + rotation);
```

#### Going further

If you want `degree` to change based on user input, then I suggest adding an input element to the page, waiting for click (or change) events and then updating your picture's styles:

```
var number_input = document.querySelector("input[type=number]#rotation");    
var element // = ...
var myExtraStyles // = ... 

// Pass in extra styles, like you width and such as above.
function rotateElement(degrees, extraStyles) {
    var rotation = "transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);";
    element.setAttribute("style", extraStyles + rotation);
}

number_input.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rotateElement(element.value, myExtraStyles);
})
```